# Get previous month range using SYSDATE()

Tags: sql-server-2008, sysdatetime

I am trying to use `sysdate()` to pull data for the previous month.

Comment: Please explain further.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @firstOfLastMonth DATE;
SET @firstOfLastMonth = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, SYSDATETIME())-1, 0);

SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE dateColumn >= @firstOfLastMonth
AND dateColumn < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, @firstOfLastMonth);
```

Here's why you don't want to use `BETWEEN` for this:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)
- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Answer (score 1):

You mean the current server time minus one month? Try the [DATEADD function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx):

```
dateadd(month, -1, sysdatetime())
```

If you want to select records with a column's value being in the past month, you could do:

```
SELECT foo
FROM bar
WHERE baz BETWEEN dateadd(month, -1, sysdatetime()) AND sysdatetime()
```

Comment: No, she meant for the previous month (e.g. January - but tomorrow that will mean February).

Comment: Also, if you mean `MONTH`, please type `MONTH`. Shorthand can get you into trouble. For example, do you think `DATEPART(y, GETDATE());` returns 2013 right now? A lot of people do. Don't be lazy.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Good point about shorthand getting you into trouble, but how in the heck did you read the OP's mind?

Comment: @lc. no super powers required. "Previous month" is a very typical phrase that *could* be interpreted as `exactly one month prior to now up to now` but almost always means `last month`.